# Target class [Api\UserController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

im getting this error in Laravel 8 after using php artisan route:list:

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Api\UserController] does not exist.

I have a controller in App\Http\Controllers\Api:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return responde()->json($users);
    }
}
```

routes/api.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController;

Route::get('users', 'Api\\UserController@index');
```

Im new at Laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are importing the `use App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController` namespace statement you can use the `::class` notation for controller class. It will also have added benefits as IDE will be able to navigate to the path unlike string

Since Laravel 8, I guess the default namespace is no longer defined to be `App\Http\Controllers` in the RouteServiceProvider, rather it is left upto the developer to define the default namespace by setting $namespace property with the desired value.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController;

Route::get('users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: Maybe you need to run `composer dump-autoload` from the terminal to refresh autoloder .

Answer (score 0):

On Larvel 8 you can't wright route as we used to before, the next syntax is this

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
user App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return responde()->json($users);
    }
}
```

**api.php:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('users', '\App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController@index');
```

**Or**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController;

Route::get('/Pages', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

[Docs for routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing)